# jquery and data-attr not working in ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This concerns a table where I show 5 rows at a time.
The follow code is working 100 percent perfect in firefox. But in ie8,
only the top row can be clicked for the editdiv to show. Whereas, in firefox
I can click on any of the five rows and the editdiv loads as expected.

Line in php file that calls the function:

```
echo "<td><a id=\"editjq\" href=\"#\" vid='".$vid."' t1='".$db->hscadd($t1)."' page='".$page."' flag='1')\">  [edit ]  </a></td>";
```

The function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a#editjq').click(function() {
    var petid = $(this).attr('vid');
    var t1 = $(this).attr('t1');
    var page = $(this).attr('page');
    var flag = $(this).attr('flag');
    $("#petdiv").hide(); 
    $.post("edit_lookup.php", {
      petid : petid,
      t1 : t1,
      page : page
    }, function(data){
     if (data.length>0){ 
       $("#editdiv").html(data); 
     } 
    });
    $(this).unbind(); 
    return false;
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant; what is the HTML that it produces and sends to the browser?

Answer (score 7):

Are you producing five rows which each have an anchor with the same `id` attribute? If so, that's your problem. It is syntactically illegal to have more than one element with the same `id`. Instead of `id="editjq"` use `class="editjq"` and `$('a.editjq').click(...)`.

Comment: @user560131 As you appear to be new to stackoverflow, let me help you a little further: when you ask a question and get an answer that satisfies your needs, you should "accept" the answer (big checkmark) so that others with a similar problem know that the answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could put this piece of jquery plugin code in your page script (just make sure that it comes after the jquery.min.js script tag);

```
    (function($){            
    var store = {};
    $.fn.extend({  
        collection : function(action, name, value) {
            var $this = this;

            var generate = function(){
                return "COLLECTION" + parseInt((Math.random() * 100000), 16);
            }

            var item_id;
            var methods = {
                put: function(){
                    item_id = $this.attr("id");
                    if(store[item_id]){
                        store[item_id][name] = value;
                    } else {                
                        while(store[item_id] && $(item_id).length > 0){
                            item_id = generate();
                        }                
                        $this.attr("id", item_id);                
                        store[item_id] = {};
                        store[item_id][name] = value;
                    }
                    return $this;
                },

                get: function(){
                    item_id = $this.attr("id");  
                    if(store[item_id] && store[item_id][name]){
                        return store[item_id][name];
                    }
                    else{
                        return null;
                    }
                },

                remove: function(){
                    item_id = $this.attr("id");
                    if(store[item_id]){
                        store[item_id][name] = null;
                    }
                    return $this;
                }
            }

            if(methods[action]){
                return methods[action]();
            } else{
                return alert(store.text.length);
            }
            return $this;
        }
    });     
})(jQuery);
```

It can be used as follows:

1. store a data value

   ```
   $(*selector*).collection("put", *DataName*, *DataValue*);
   ```
2. retreive a data value

   ```
   var referencing_variable = $(*selector*).collection("get", *DataName*);
   ```
3. delete a data value

   ```
   $(*selector*).collection("remove", *DataName*);
   ```

This is a cross browser solution. Though i have only tested it with Jquery 1.5.1